# How do I make footer stick to the bottom of the page and not cover the content

Tags: javascript, html, css, footer

I am creating a contact page for an active web project I'm working on. I have a fixed footer, however I do not want it to cover the contact form and map. I would like the page scrolled to see the footer at the bottom of the page. Please help.

I have tried several tutorials including the one with min height and margin-top which did not work.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  background: #3a8ace;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.6s;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

header .name {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  align-items: center;
}

header .navbar ul {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

header .navbar ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

header .navbar ul li a {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
}

.active,
.a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

header .navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

header .navbar ul li ul {
  /*     position: absolute; */
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}

#menu-bar {
  display: none;
}

header label {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  color: #333;
}

.topic {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  .menu,
  .main,
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    main {
      margin-top: 80px;
    }
    header {
      padding: 30px;
    }
    header label {
      display: initial;
    }
    header .navbar {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: #fff;
      border-top: 1 px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    header .navbar ul li {
      width: 100%;
    }
    header .navbar ul li ul {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #menu-bar:checked~.navbar {
      display: initial;
    }
  }
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: auto 0;
  margin-bottom: auto 0;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.contact-in {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #666;
}

.contact-map {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex: 50%;
}

.contact-map iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.contact-form {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-form h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.contact-form-txt {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  border-radius: 50px;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.contact-form-txt::placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}

.contact-form-textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.contact-form-textarea::placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}

.contact-form-btn {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #3a8ace;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #111;
}

footer .content {
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .content p,
a {
  color: #fff;
}

footer .content .box {
  width: 33%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

footer .content .topic {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

footer .content p {
  text-align: justify;
}

footer .content .lower .topic {
  margin: 24px 0 5px 0;
}

footer .content .lower i {
  padding-right: 16px;
}

footer .content .middle {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

footer .content .middle a {
  line-height: 32px;
}

footer .content .right input[type="text"] {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 2px solid #222222;
}

footer .content .right input[type="submit"] {
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  background: #eb2f06;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #eb2f06;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.content .right input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #eb2f06;
}

footer .content .media-icons a {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 43px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #222222;
  margin: 30px 5px 0 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.content .media-icons a:hover {
  border-color: #eb2f06;
}

footer .bottom {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 0 40px 5px 0;
}

footer .bottom a {
  color: #eb2f06;
}

footer a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #eb2f06;
}

@media (max-width:1100px) {
  footer .content .middle {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:950px) {
  footer .content .box {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .content .right {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:560px) {
  footer {
    position: relative;
  }
  footer .content .box {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  footer .content .middle {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title> Contact Us </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="https://ecj.com.jm/"> <img src="img/ecjLogo.png" id="logo"> </a>
    <center>
      <div class="name"> ECJ </div>
    </center>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-bar">
    <label fr="menu-bar">Menu</label>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Application</a></li>
        <li> <a href="help.html"> Help </a></li>
        <li> <a href="https://ecj.com.jm/about-the-ecj/about/"> About </a></li>
        <li> <a href="contact.html" active> Contact Us </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="contact-in">
    <div class="contact-map">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d948.8047317660009!2d-76.78757370737829!3d17.968548688002155!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8edb41467940d125%3A0x3c0567402b03262b!2sElectoral%20Office%20of%20Jamaica!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sjm!4v1679605097317!5m2!1sen!2sjm"
        width="100%" height="auto" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="contact-form">
      <h1> Contact Us</h1>
      <h3>Address:</h3>
      <p>GIS Department, <br> Electoral Office of Jamaica, <br> 43 Duke Street, Kingston, Jamaica</p> <br>
      <p>Tel: (876)-922-0425-9</p>
      <p>Toll-Free: 1-888-991-VOTE(8683)</p>
      <p>Fax: (876)-922-4058</p><br>
      <p>Email: gisdepartment@eoj.com.jm</p>
      <br>
      <form action="mailto:gisdepartment@eoj.com.jm" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
        Subject: <br>
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Your Full Name" class="contact-form-txt" required> <br> Email: <br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Work Email" class="contact-form-txt" required><br> Message:
        <br>
        <textarea id="Message" name="Message" class="contact-form-textarea" rows="6" maxlength="3000" required cols="30" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" class="contact-form-btn" value="Send">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <footer>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="left box">
        <div class="upper">
          <div class="topic">About us</div>
          <p>CodingLab is a channel where you can learn HTML, CSS, and also JavaScript along with creative CSS Animations and Effects.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="lower">
          <div class="topic">Contact us</div>
          <div class="phone">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i>+007 9089 6767</a>
          </div>
          <div class="email">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>abc@gmail.com</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="middle box">
        <div class="topic">Our Services</div>
        <div><a href="#">Web Design, Development</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Web UX Design, Reasearch</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Web User Interface Design</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Theme Development, Design</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Mobile Application Design</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Wire raming & Prototyping</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="right box">
        <div class="topic">Subscribe us</div>
        <form action="#">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email address">
          <input type="submit" name="" value="Send">
          <div class="media-icons">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Copyright © 2020 <a href="#">CodingLab</a> All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kameron posted a great answer.

Here are my additional recommendations for resolving other issues you may encounter.

Always start with this as the top of your CSS file. The order of html and * is important:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
```

Then, set `flex` to zero on all direct descendants, while setting it to one on `main`

This is what forces the footer to the bottom. `main` will always consume empty vertical space. This also allows the footer to be pushed down when there is more content.

```
header, footer {
  flex: 0;
}
main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Feedback is appreciated. These are all good points also.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `fixed` on `footer` and `height: 150vh` on `body`. It makes more sense to use `flex` on body instead of `grid` with `flex-direction: column;` and `justify-content: space-between;` to evenly space `<header>`, `<main>`, and `<footer>`.

Then set `header` to `sticky` and nest your contact form in the `<main>` element.

The `<main>` element denotes the content of a webpage that relates to the central topic of the page. Hence, the contact form.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: Sticky;
  background: #3a8ace;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.6s;
  padding: 20px 50px;
}

header .name {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  align-items: center;
}

header .navbar ul {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

header .navbar ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

header .navbar ul li a {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
}

.active,
.a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

header .navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

header .navbar ul li ul {
  /*     position: absolute; */
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}

#menu-bar {
  display: none;
}

header label {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  color: #333;
}

.topic {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  .menu,
  .main,
  .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
  @media (max-width: 991px) {
    main {
      margin-top: 80px;
    }
    header {
      padding: 30px;
    }
    header label {
      display: initial;
    }
    header .navbar {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: #fff;
      border-top: 1 px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
    header .navbar ul li {
      width: 100%;
    }
    header .navbar ul li ul {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    #menu-bar:checked~.navbar {
      display: initial;
    }
  }
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: auto 0;
  margin-bottom: auto 0;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.contact-in {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #666;
}

.contact-map {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex: 50%;
}

.contact-map iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.contact-form {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.contact-form h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.contact-form-txt {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  border-radius: 50px;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.contact-form-txt::placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}

.contact-form-textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.contact-form-textarea::placeholder {
  color: #aaa;
}

.contact-form-btn {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #3a8ace;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #111;
}

footer .content {
  max-width: 1350px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .content p,
a {
  color: #fff;
}

footer .content .box {
  width: 33%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

footer .content .topic {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

footer .content p {
  text-align: justify;
}

footer .content .lower .topic {
  margin: 24px 0 5px 0;
}

footer .content .lower i {
  padding-right: 16px;
}

footer .content .middle {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

footer .content .middle a {
  line-height: 32px;
}

footer .content .right input[type="text"] {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 2px solid #222222;
}

footer .content .right input[type="submit"] {
  height: 42px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  background: #eb2f06;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #eb2f06;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.content .right input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #eb2f06;
}

footer .content .media-icons a {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 43px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #222222;
  margin: 30px 5px 0 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.content .media-icons a:hover {
  border-color: #eb2f06;
}

footer .bottom {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  padding: 0 40px 5px 0;
}

footer .bottom a {
  color: #eb2f06;
}

footer a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #eb2f06;
}

@media (max-width:1100px) {
  footer .content .middle {
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:950px) {
  footer .content .box {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .content .right {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:560px) {
  footer {
    position: relative;
  }
  footer .content .box {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  footer .content .middle {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

main {
  padding: 1em 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title> Contact Us </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="https://ecj.com.jm/"> <img src="img/ecjLogo.png" id="logo"> </a>
    <center>
      <div class="name"> ECJ </div>
    </center>
    <input type="checkbox" id="menu-bar">
    <label fr="menu-bar">Menu</label>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="index.html">Application</a></li>
        <li> <a href="help.html"> Help </a></li>
        <li> <a href="https://ecj.com.jm/about-the-ecj/about/"> About </a></li>
        <li> <a href="contact.html" active> Contact Us </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main>
  <div class="contact-in">
    <div class="contact-map">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d948.8047317660009!2d-76.78757370737829!3d17.968548688002155!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x8edb41467940d125%3A0x3c0567402b03262b!2sElectoral%20Office%20of%20Jamaica!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sjm!4v1679605097317!5m2!1sen!2sjm"
        width="100%" height="auto" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="contact-form">
      <h1> Contact Us</h1>
      <h3>Address:</h3>
      <p>GIS Department, <br> Electoral Office of Jamaica, <br> 43 Duke Street, Kingston, Jamaica</p> <br>
      <p>Tel: (876)-922-0425-9</p>
      <p>Toll-Free: 1-888-991-VOTE(8683)</p>
      <p>Fax: (876)-922-4058</p><br>
      <p>Email: gisdepartment@eoj.com.jm</p>
      <br>
      <form action="mailto:gisdepartment@eoj.com.jm" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
        Subject: <br>
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Your Full Name" class="contact-form-txt" required> <br> Email: <br>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Work Email" class="contact-form-txt" required><br> Message:
        <br>
        <textarea id="Message" name="Message" class="contact-form-textarea" rows="6" maxlength="3000" required cols="30" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" class="contact-form-btn" value="Send">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="left box">
        <div class="upper">
          <div class="topic">About us</div>
          <p>CodingLab is a channel where you can learn HTML, CSS, and also JavaScript along with creative CSS Animations and Effects.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="lower">
          <div class="topic">Contact us</div>
          <div class="phone">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone-volume"></i>+007 9089 6767</a>
          </div>
          <div class="email">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>abc@gmail.com</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="middle box">
        <div class="topic">Our Services</div>
        <div><a href="#">Web Design, Development</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Web UX Design, Reasearch</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Web User Interface Design</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Theme Development, Design</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Mobile Application Design</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">Wire raming & Prototyping</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="right box">
        <div class="topic">Subscribe us</div>
        <form action="#">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email address">
          <input type="submit" name="" value="Send">
          <div class="media-icons">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <p>Copyright © 2020 <a href="#">CodingLab</a> All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```css
body {
    min-height: 100vh; 
    display: flex; 
    flex-direction: column;
}
footer{ 
    margin-top: auto; 
}
```

Here, you force your body to be the height of the screen and your footer to be as far as possible from the top of the screen! here is a useful link where I found the info: https://dev.to/nehalahmadkhan/how-to-make-footer-stick-to-bottom-of-web-page-3i14